# The best and fastest way to remove special string from string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

E.g

```
$stringOriginal = "C D E F G H I J K L M N";

$stringRemove = "E F M";
```

And I want to remove the string of $stringRemove from $stringOriginal!So, I can get the

```
$result = "C D G H I J K L N";
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Are these always going to be letters? or are these words? (I guess I'm asking for real data, if it's not a security risk) as there are a plethora of options to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-preg method

```
$stringOriginal = "C D E F G H I J K L M N";
$stringRemove = "E F M";

$removals = explode(' ',$stringRemove);
$result = str_replace($removals,'',$stringOriginal);
$result = str_replace('  ',' ',$result);
```

Comment: This gets my upvote, the other answers that simply list a single `str_replace()` call are either unclear or flat out wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock/@MarkBaker: Unless these are tokens and `$needle` is in another token.

Comment: At the end you're replacing double spaces with one space. In case of multiple removals, this will not help. A recursive solution can help, however IMHO this is not anymore elegant at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_replace](http://docs.php.net/str_replace) with `$stringRemove` exploded into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming *nothing more* than what was provided in your question, my initial thought would be to use `preg_replace` and look for these characters (with optional spaces):

```
$stringOriginal = "C D E F G H I J K L M N";
print preg_replace('/(E|F|M)\s+?/', '', $stringOriginal);
```

Which outputs: `C D G H I J K L N`

Comment: Though I don't believe regex is a best solution, I would like to mention the `\b` directive for regex.

Comment: @Brad Excellent suggestion, however I was merely working from what the question asked rather than what the question might have represented. If the user is looking for words rather than single char letters, the approach ought to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result= str_replace($stringRemove, "", $stringOriginal);
```

But then your $stringRemove will be `array('E', 'F', 'M');` and not the format you're using.

Answer (score 1):

using preg_replace:

```
//no spaces needed in the filter 'E F M' should be 'EFM' for this function
function specialFilter($body, $filter) {
  return preg_replace("/[$filter]/", '', $body);
}

//example usage
$filteredMessage = specialFilter('C D E F G H I J K L M N', 'EFM');

//if double spaces are not allowed after the filtered elements are removed run this
$filteredMessage = str_replace('  ', ' ', $filteredMessage);
```

see: [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) & [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do :

```
echo implode(' ', str_replace(explode(' ', $stringRemove), '', explode(' ', $stringOriginal)));
```

It would return "C D   G H I J K L  N", so you would still have to check for incorrect spaces (this is easy).

Comment: Bingo. This would be my direction as well, given these are tokens and not just letters. If it's just removing an alphabet, `str_replace` suits the need. If `$needle` may be in another entry, this is a best-fit.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be using str_replace, but my fear is there are tokens and the values could be nested within another value. Maybe I'm wrong and this is overkill, but the solution either way:

```
$stringOriginal = "C D E F G H I J K L M N";
$stringRemove = "E F M";

var_dump(implode(' ',array_diff(explode(' ',$stringOriginal),explode(' ',$stringRemove))));
```

results in:

```
string(17) "C D G H I J K L N"
```